# How can I show in a single SQL query: What departments don't have any employees and what employees don't have a department (Oracle SQL)?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I've been trying to figure this out for a while and still no luck. Would I combine the following with a 'is null'?

```
select distinct 
       e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.department_id,
       d.department_id, d.location_id
from employees e 
  join departments d on (e.department_id = d.department_id)
```

Comment: Google for ORACLE FULL OUTER JOIN.  Basically you need to do a full outer join and select where left or right is null.  One way to do it in Oracle is to use a UNION, but Google has lots more info.

Answer (score 2):

Example based on Joe's comment

```
select distinct 
       e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.department_id,
       d.department_id, d.location_id
from employees e 
  full outer join departments d on (e.department_id = d.department_id)
where e.department_id is null or d.department_id is null
```

Or this way with `union`

```
select distinct 
       e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.department_id,
       d.department_id, d.location_id
from employees e 
  left outer join departments d on (e.department_id = d.department_id)
where d.department_id is null 
union 
select distinct 
       e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.department_id,
       d.department_id, d.location_id
from employees e 
  right outer join departments d on (e.department_id = d.department_id)
where e.department_id is null
```